# PHP current() returns false when passing a valid array to it

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array with size=1 and when i try to get the current array its returns false but the array has values.

```
    $article=getArticle($id); 
    if(is_array($article)) 

    { $article=current($article); }
```

the getArticle returns multidimensional array and when var_dump before current i can see the array.
If var_dump after current i get false.

if i use the code above (because the array size=1)

```
            if(is_array($article)) 
            { 
                    foreach($article as $k=>$v)
               {
            $article=$v;
               }
           }
```

It works without any problem

Whats wrong with current?

Please help

===============EDIT========================

This is the var_dump before current
I have remove the content and summary because are large texts

```
array(1) {
      [529]=>
      array(14) {
        ["articles_id"]=>
        string(3) "529"
        ["issue"]=>
        string(3) "161"
        ["membership_type"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["el"]=>
        array(9) {
          ["title"]=>
          string(23) "AUTOBIANCHI A112 ABARTH"
          ["url"]=>
          string(23) "autobianchi-a112-abarth"
          ["summary"]=>
          string(397) " i have remove it 
    "
          ["content"]=>
          string(11580) " i have remove it too large
     "
          ["meta_keywords"]=>
          string(23) "AUTOBIANCHI,A112,ABARTH"
          ["meta_description"]=>
          string(402) " "
          ["created"]=>
          string(10) "1362076380"
          ["last_updated"]=>
          string(1) "0"
          ["status"]=>
          string(1) "1"
        }
        ["categories_id"]=>
        string(2) "12"
        ["authors_id"]=>
        string(2) "16"
        ["brands_id"]=>
        string(2) "36"
        ["models_id"]=>
        string(3) "206"
        ["engines_id"]=>
        string(3) "174"
        ["o-categories"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["values"]=>
          array(1) {
            [12]=>
            array(15) {
              ["categories_id"]=>
              string(2) "12"
              ["object_id"]=>
              string(1) "1"
              ["parent_id"]=>
              string(1) "0"
              ["path"]=>
              string(2) "12"
              ["handler"]=>
              string(0) ""
              ["icon"]=>
              string(0) ""
              ["tpl"]=>
              string(12) "articles.php"
              ["alias"]=>
              string(1) "0"
              ["is_nav"]=>
              string(1) "1"
              ["pos"]=>
              string(2) "10"
              ["depth"]=>
              string(1) "0"
              ["cts"]=>
              string(0) ""
              ["mts"]=>
              string(0) ""
              ["configuration"]=>
              string(0) ""
              ["el"]=>
              array(15) {
                ["categories_id"]=>
                string(2) "12"
                ["lang"]=>
                string(2) "el"
                ["category_name"]=>
                string(13) "Classic"
                ["sub_title"]=>
                string(0) ""
                ["summary"]=>
                string(0) ""
                ["image"]=>
                string(0) ""
                ["html_code"]=>
                string(0) ""
                ["meta_title"]=>
                string(0) ""
                ["url"]=>
                string(13) "classic"
                ["url_path"]=>
                string(13) "classic"
                ["meta_keywords"]=>
                string(0) ""
                ["meta_description"]=>
                string(0) ""
                ["created"]=>
                string(10) "1355235888"
                ["last_updated"]=>
                string(1) "0"
                ["status"]=>
                string(1) "1"
              }
            }
          }
        }
        ["o-authors"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["values"]=>
          array(1) {
            [16]=>
            array(4) {
              ["authors_id"]=>
              string(2) "16"
              ["object_id"]=>
              string(2) "26"
              ["image"]=>
              string(0) ""
              ["el"]=>
              array(9) {
                ["authors_id"]=>
                string(2) "16"
                ["lang"]=>
                string(2) "el"
                ["name"]=>
                string(31) "Last First"
                ["last_name"]=>
                string(10) "Last"
                ["first_name"]=>
                string(20) "First"
                ["nick_name"]=>
                string(0) ""
                ["created"]=>
                string(10) "1360567827"
                ["last_updated"]=>
                string(1) "0"
                ["status"]=>
                string(1) "1"
              }
            }
          }
        }
        ["o-brands"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["values"]=>
          array(1) {
            [36]=>
            array(6) {
              ["brands_id"]=>
              string(2) "36"
              ["object_id"]=>
              string(2) "17"
              ["brand_name"]=>
              string(11) "AUTOBIANCHI"
              ["created"]=>
              string(10) "1363179463"
              ["last_updated"]=>
              string(1) "0"
              ["status"]=>
              string(1) "1"
            }
          }
        }
        ["o-models"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["values"]=>
          array(1) {
            [206]=>
            array(7) {
              ["models_id"]=>
              string(3) "206"
              ["object_id"]=>
              string(2) "18"
              ["brands_id"]=>
              string(2) "36"
              ["model_name"]=>
              string(11) "A112 ABARTH"
              ["created"]=>
              string(10) "1363179480"
              ["last_updated"]=>
              string(1) "0"
              ["status"]=>
              string(1) "1"
            }
          }
        }
        ["o-engines"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["values"]=>
          array(1) {
            [174]=>
            array(6) {
              ["engines_id"]=>
              string(3) "174"
              ["object_id"]=>
              string(2) "19"
              ["engine"]=>
              string(5) "1.050"
              ["created"]=>
              string(10) "1363179448"
              ["last_updated"]=>
              string(1) "0"
              ["status"]=>
              string(1) "1"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: could you post the var_dump of article?

Comment: @Mario : you can check the var_dump i have edit the Q

Comment: Could you post getArticle function?

Comment: Instead of `$article = current($article)` you could do `$article = array_shift($article)`. Here is [array_shift documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try

```
$article=getArticle($id); 
if (is_array($article)) {
    $article = reset($article); 
}
```

or

```
$article=getArticle($id); 
if (is_array($article)) {
    $article = array_shift($article); 
}
```

You can look into the [documentation about reset](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) and the [documentation about array_shift](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php).

Comment: +1 array_shift is working but still its not logical that the current fails

Comment: The documentation states `an internal pointer [...] is initialized to the first element inserted into the array`. Not sure how the array is created in your code but perhaps you are using a function that doesn't `insert` values in the array.

Comment: I add on getArtilces before return an reset on array and worked fine.Thanks you saved my day

Answer (score 1):

If you copy array in getArticle() function then its internal pointer is lost.

I think this is the reason, it returns false.

Comment: +1 for your notice and knowledge but I wiil check if i copy the table, thanks